# C# Asp.net RazorPdf / iTextSharp image from base64

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, itext, mvcrazortopdf

I'm using MvcRazorToPdf in my Asp.net MVC5 project to create pdfs from model.
That works fine, but I want to include an image from a base64 string, because I don't want to save the generated image.

```
System.Drawing.Image img = generator.GenerateImage();
string imageBase64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(Helper.ImageToByteArray(img));
string imageDataURL = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", imageBase64Data);
ViewBag.Image = imageDataURL;

return new PdfActionResult(myobject);
```

...

```
<img src="@ViewBag.Image" />
```

Working fine, if showing the image in a normal view, but the pdf doesn't show the image.

Thank you for help or alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

In MvcRazorToPdf you can only use the full (local) path to the image file like this:

```
@model MvcRazorToPdfExample.Models.PdfExample
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_PdfLayout.cshtml";
    var imagePath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images");
}

 <img src="@imagePath\avatar.jpg" alt="mug shot" />
```

Base64 images are not supported as far as I know. I copied the snippet above from the example view at:
https://github.com/andyhutch77/MvcRazorToPdf/blob/master/MvcRazorToPdfExample/Views/Pdf/Index.cshtml

Answer (score 1):

Probably I'm answering too late. If your needs for a base64 string based image is to avoid store the image in the filesystem, you can write an Action that returns the image file and reference that url in the `img` tag:

```
public ActionResult GetImage(/*probably some id*/)
{ 
    System.Drawing.Image img = generator.GenerateImage();
    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    var bytes = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
    return File(bytes, "image/jpg"); // if your image is jpg
}
```

And then your razor will look like:

```
<img src='@Url.Action("GetImage", "Images", null, Request.Url.Scheme)' />
```

Note the use of `Request.Url.Scheme` `Url.Action` overload is VERY important, because iTextSharp needs the full qualified URL.

Comment: This sounds like a great idea for not storing the image!!!! I will try it right now.

Comment: I was very hopeful when I saw this, but it still doesn't work for me with the latest RazorPDF/iTestSharp